# Average with Multiple Criteria in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have 4 columns in table called year, product, status, value. I want the MEASURE average of value only for specific status and for specific year so how i can write the average DAX with multiple criteria.

In excel i can easily write as averageifs(value, year=2021, status="Sold").

I WANT THE MEASURE ONLY.

Please suggest. i tried every and did not get success to add multiple criteria's.

Regards,
SK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below measure-

```
average_ =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_table_name[value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[year] = 2021
            && your_table_name[status] = "sold"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you,, i was playing around these DAX only but couldn't reach exactly same.

Comment: Now i am facing another problem, please see if you can help. i am using this measure in five different cards in visualization and adding one more filter but that filter is not making any change to this measure (in all the cards i am getting same value. e.g. i have one more column called "bucket" and have value 1K, 1 to 2K, 2 to 5K , 5 to 10K, 10K. if this is not possible then i think i have to change my approach to show this but i want to show this in separate card only.

Comment: You can add visual level filter for your 5 cards and set bucket accordingly.